# Mac connecting to dead NFS

Tags: mac, nfs

My mac tries to connect to an old NFS that I used at an old job. I tried everything and looked at every related question asked on this forum.

At the time I had it set on auto connect. But since I quit there, it still tries to connect to it. So every time my mac reboots, I get an error that the server "can't be found". It's really getting annoying. I tries the Disky Utility, removing it from my server list cmd+k. It did not help